# Generate a new message from a specific node after a condition

Tags: c++, omnet++

I am using this piece of code:

```
void Txc13::initialize()
{
// Module 0 sends the first message
if (getIndex() == 0) {
    // Boot the process scheduling the initial message as a self-message.
    TicTocMsg13 *msg = generateMessage();
    scheduleAt(0.0, msg);
}
}
TicTocMsg13 *Txc13::generateMessage()
{
   // Produce source and destination addresses.
   int src = getIndex();  // our module index
   int dest = 8;
   char msgname[20];
   sprintf(msgname, "tic-%d-to-%d", src, dest);
   // Create message object and set source and destination field.
   TicTocMsg13 *msg = new TicTocMsg13(msgname);
   msg->setSource(src);
   msg->setDestination(dest);
   return msg;
}
```

And it generates a message which starts in the getIndex() value of 0 where, I start the simulation and it reaches the destination node 8.
Now I want to generate another message that when the first message reaches the node 8, the new message could start in node 2 and reach node 4. Is it possible to do that in the same simulation?

Comment: In your scenario node 0 sends a message to the node 8. So how the node 2 will be informed, that the node 8 received this message?

Comment: i know that it is not a real example, what I´m trying to figure out is how can point to an other node to create a new message. For example, how can I send simultaneously from 2 different nodes a message?

Answer (score 0):

As @jerzy-d suggested, you need to have some kind of out of band communication between the nodes that allows node2 to start sending the message when node8 received it. The easiest way to do that is to factor out the functionality that generates and sends the message to a separate function. Once the message arrives to the final destination draw a random number (i.e. which node will send the next message (in your example node2) then get a pointer to NODE2 and call the message generator method on that node. This way the out of band communication is done by direct ,method calls between the nodes.